# ADB will not install APK file on Android Emulator. Just says: "Performing Streamed Install"

Tags: android-emulator, apk, adb

ADB will not install my 32-bit APK file on an emulator. But it is not showing any error message when trying to install it:

In Android Studio 4.2.2 (on my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS laptop) I installed an emulator: Pixel_2_API_27_Android_8.1_x86_

I then open a Terminal window and do this:

```
:~$ /home/henrik/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully

:~$ which adb

:~$ /home/henrik/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
List of devices attached

:~$ emulator @Pixel_2_API_27_Android_8.1_x86_

emulator: Android emulator version 30.7.4.0 (build_id 7453540) (CL:N/A)

handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf

cannot add library /home/henrik/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so: failed

added library /home/henrik/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so

cannot add library /home/henrik/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so.1: full

emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:315: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local

emulator: INFO: EmulatorAdvertisement.cpp:93: Advertising in: /run/user/1000/avd/running/pid_68812.ini

qemu-system-i386: warning: TSC frequency mismatch between VM (2711993 kHz) and host (2711986 kHz), and TSC scaling unavailable
```

In a new Terminal tab I do this:

```
:~$ /home/henrik/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l

List of devices attached

emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86 model:Android_SDK_built_for_x86 device:generic_x86 transport_id:1

:~$ /home/henrik/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 install /mnt/4AF15A0435E762B4/mypython/storage/bin/storage-0.1-armeabi-v7a-debug.apk

Performing Streamed Install
```

But then, nothing happens. (I waited a very long time.)

If I copy the APK file to my physical MOTO G5 Android 8.1.0 phone and install it, at least I get en error message showing that it DID install.